# Property history does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, frontend

I am trying to kick off a new project using `React` and `TypeScript`,
one of the things I stuck with is `Router`, for some reason TypeScript does not acknowledge `history` property, though it should be available [according to the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Router/history-object).

My component

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

let history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider>
        <Router history={history} > {/* Error is in this line */}
            <div />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Error message:

```
Error:(11, 11) TS2339:Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes 
& IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; ...'.
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: which version of react-router you are using ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you are using react-router-v4

You can not pass a history to a `<BrowserRouter>`, as it creates its own history object

If you are creating your own history Object use `<Router>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` and then pass history object

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
<Router history={history}> <Router/>
```

You can read more on history in  [react-router-v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4895)

Comment: Ah, I should have noticed that I am not actually using `Router` but `BrowserRouter` with alias `Router`... Silly mistake. Thank you, I am really appreciated your help!

Comment: Glad to help you out :)

Comment: Typescript complains <Router> does not have basename. How to get both basename and history? Thanks

Comment: Looks like v6 broke this as well.